# Mostrar/Ocultar Tab Bar ítem en swift

Tags: swift, xcode

lo que quiero hacer es teniendo una APP que se  que se conecta a un sistema de Admin y usuario. Cuando el admin acceda la Tab Bar muestre elementos que no están disponibles para un usuario que inició sesión no como admin. Hasta ahora lo único que encontré fue como ocultar la barra completa nada más. Agradezco sus respuestas

```
if let tabBarItem = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[3] as? UITabBarItem {
        tabBarItem.enabled = false
}
```

Comment: tabbar.isHidden=true ? eso buscas?

Comment: No, quiero poder mostrar distintas Tab Bar ítem para un administrador y para un empleado eso lo que busco

Comment: y puedes poner el código de lo que has intentado?

Comment: Con ese código que agregue no me deja tocar el ítem pero lo que yo quiero es eliminarlo de la Tab Bar

Comment: creo lo mejor sería que crearas un enum y le pases los items al tabBar dependiendo el case, si es admin le pasas los items con tabBarController.tabBar.items = [item1, item2, item3, item4]... y si no es administrador le pasas [item1, item2]. no se si es lo que buscas...    ahora otra podría ser que crearas dos tabs y le pasas los items que necesitas, y simplemente creas un boolenao y con ese validas si es administrador, yo al menos no he encontrado la forma de esconder o reemplazar un item de un tabBar... pero si ya encontraste la solución no dudes en colocarla como respuesta. saludos!